# why invoking thread count is more than execution of thread count in C program?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

In the code below, I create a thread having a loop which will perform a full iteration when I invoke the condition. However, if i am invoking it 1000 times, the `invoking_thread` value is different than `exec_thread` at the end of `main`. What is happening, and how can I fix this issue? I do not want to exit the thread running `threadfunc`, because I may need to use it for further operations.

```
#include < pthread.h> 
#include < stdio.h>

pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; 
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; 
int invoking_thread = 0, exec_thread = 0; 
pthread_t pth; 

void *threadfunc(void *parm) 
{ 
    int x; 
    for (;;) { 
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); 
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); 
        //printf("Inside the thread %d\n", ins); 
        exec_thread++; 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
    } 
    return NULL; 
} 


void create_thread () { 
    pthread_create(&pth,NULL,threadfunc,"foo"); 
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
    create_thread(); 
    int y = 0; 
    while (1) { 
        if (y == 1000) { 
            break; 
        } 
        y++; 
        invoking_thread++; 
        printf("Count: Invoked %d and Inside : %d\n", invoking_thread, exec_thread); 
        pthread_cond_signal( &cond ); 
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex ); 
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex ); 
    } 
    printf("Count: Invoked %d and Inside : %d\n", invoking_thread, exec_thread); 
    printf("Main completed\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

DETAILS of Further Explanation:
I can tell you my whole situation: An array of 1000 size is initialized with 0 value. 1 thread is started with infinite loop. for 1000 iterations i pass the signal to thread to increment the value of each element of an array. After passing signal, these values are multiplied by 2 in a loop. In next step, again 1000 signals are passed to thread to increment the value of each element of an array. Then, same as previously, all the element values are multiplied by 2 in a loop. Then result is printed.

Now, adding some chunks, most of the time i am getting segmentation fault. and rest of the time i am not getting desired value.

```
  #include < pthread.h>

  #include < stdio.h>

   pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

   pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

   int invoking_thread = 0, exec_thread = 0, signal_count = 0;

   pthread_t pth;

   int res[1000];

 void *threadfunc(void *parm) { 

for (;;) { 

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); 

    while (signal_count == 0)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); 

    signal_count--; // consume a signal

//printf("Inside the thread res[%d]++\n", exec_thread);

    exec_thread++; 

res[exec_thread]++;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 

  }

  return NULL; 

  }


  void create_thread () {

      pthread_create(&pth,NULL,threadfunc,"foo");

  }


  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {

create_thread();

int y;

for (y = 0;y<1000;y++) {
    res[y] = 0;
}
y = 0;
while (1) {
    if (y == 1000) {
        break;
    }
    y++;
    invoking_thread++;
    //printf("Count: Invoked %d and Inside : %d\n", invoking_thread, exec_thread);
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex ); 
        signal_count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex ); 
        pthread_cond_signal( &cond ); 
}
printf("Count: Invoked %d and Inside : %d\n", invoking_thread, exec_thread);

for (y = 0;y<1000;y++) {
    res[y] = res[y]*2;
}
exec_thread = 0;
y = 0;
while (1) {
    if (y == 1000) {
        break;
    }
    y++;
    invoking_thread++;
    //printf("Count: Invoked %d and Inside : %d\n", invoking_thread, exec_thread);
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex ); 
        signal_count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex ); 
        pthread_cond_signal( &cond ); 
}
printf("Count: Invoked %d and Inside : %d\n", invoking_thread, exec_thread);

for (y = 0;y<1000;y++) {
    res[y] = res[y]*2;
}

// result
for (y = 0;y<1000;y++) {
    printf("%d result for %d\n",res[y], y);
}

printf("Main completed\n");
return 0;
  }
```

Hence my question is, thread invocation should have to wait after first 1000 signals, which it is not waiting and then let the code do the calculations and then it should be allowed to do the further 1000 invocations. and so on to get the desired result. Hope i am able to explain my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pthread_cond_signal()` will wake any thread waiting on the condition **if** there is a thread waiting. If not, then that call will do nothing. This is most probably what happens in your case. There are several subsequent calls to `pthread_cond_signal()`, while the worker thread is not actually sleeping.

To ensure one invoke-one worker pass you will have to use two `pthread_cond_t` - one to signal starting of worker, second for notifying that the work has ended. Another is to busy wait until 1000 jobs have been done. Here's a modified code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    create_thread();
    int y = 0;
    int executed = 0;
    while (executed <1000) {
        invoking_thread++;
        printf("Count: Invoked %d and Inside : %d\n", invoking_thread, exec_thread);
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
        executed = exec_thread; // read inside mutex to ensure variable visibility
        pthread_cond_signal( &cond );
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
    }
    printf("Count: Invoked %d and Inside : %d\n", invoking_thread, exec_thread);
    printf("Main completed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just compiled the program and confirmed this to be the problem. The main thread runs like a bull at a gate - which sends 1,000 signals, but the other thread never gets a chance to receive them all before the main thread exits. If you put a sleep into the main thread then the other thread will receive the signals.

Comment: Thanks for you concern. But adding sleep and delay will not help me attaining the speed. Is there any way so that i can get signal so that all 1000 get completed. which will help me adding checks after this

Comment: @Vishwadeep the simplest thing to do would be to busy wait in main (and keep signalling) ntil the thread has actually done it's work 1000 times.

Comment: @Vishwadeep I edited my answer with some code. Also, look at David's answer, its the more general and more optimal solution.

Comment: @Vishwadeep if you make your child thread exit after 1,000 signals, and add a thread join in your main thread, then you'll get your signals. At some point the main thread has to take a break so the child thread can execute.

Comment: yes i am working on David's answer only. Hope this helps. I guess i am confused with myself only. I am not able to do wait after the code to perform further steps. Once again thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Condition variables are stateless. You are expecting the condition variable to have a "signaled" state. It does not. If you want to associate state with the condition variable, you must do so. You can have a "signal_count" variable and then do this:

```
void *threadfunc(void *parm) 
{ 
    int x; 
    for (;;) { 
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); 
        while (signal_count == 0)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); 
        signal_count--; // consume a signal
        //printf("Inside the thread %d\n", ins); 
        exec_thread++; 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
    } 
    return NULL; 
}
```

Similarly:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex ); 
    signal_count++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex ); 
    pthread_cond_signal( &cond );
```

Notice that the mutex protects the state, you must implement the state, you must not call `pthread_cond_wait` unless you know you need to wait, and you must not assume the state has any particular value when `pthread_cond_wait` returns. That is how you use a condition variable.

Comment: Thanks David, i tried the same using signal count. Still i am not able to get the same number. And one more thing, if i am removing repetitive print statements, then difference between invocation and execution is increasing.

Comment: Please tell me if i understood wrong. Using condition variable i cannot depend on the count of execution. I have find a way to collect the count using separate variables, like you show as signal_count.

Comment: @Vishwadeep Post the code that isn't working. It's likely you have some other bug. I'm not sure what you mean by "depend on the count of execution". What I would say is that you can't expect a condition variable to change state (say between "signaled" and "unsignaled") because it doesn't have state. Also, you have to remember that `pthread_cond_wait` is not a conditional wait, it's an UNconditional wait *for* a condition.

Comment: Hi @David i had edited my question with further explanation and full code. Please check through it.

Comment: i guess now i am getting it better @David Schwartz , you are using signal_count as an semaphore and waiting for signal to be consumed. and (signal_count == 0) means my thread is free to execute. At least i did catch up the thought. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting to add `pthread_join()` in the main to wait until all threads are finished calculating?

[[See here]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html)

Comment: using pthread_join() will wait for whole thread to complete. I did't want to complete the thread. Thread should remain still active, so that i can add more code further.

Comment: but if your main thread is exiting before all the threads are finished then how can you get the same calculation count?

Comment: The thread does it's job indefinitely. That's not the problem.

Comment: After 1000 invocations and 1000 calculations, i want add some checks and approach further for next 1000 calculations. But here, before completing first 1000 calculations, it is coming out and can invoke next 1000 invocations if added. I want to add some kind of wait so that let first 1000 to be calculated first and then move further. Hope i am able to explain myself

Comment: yes Dariusz, thread is not my issue, it is working more than fine. But wait is not happening so that i can get all 1000 calculations.